# Trying to remove files and clean hard drive on windows, but cannot due to failed linux dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I'm trying to reset windows [using this option on windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmXlC.png), but it fails. I suspect it is due to a failed linux dual boot I attempted in the past, which is still taking space on the drive, which is why Windows cannot clear the entire drive. 
[I can boot from it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfJYq.jpg) (it's on the hard drive, no external device), and I believe it is on Disk 0 partition 1, taking up 100 MB  [as shown on disk management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVwR2.png). "Acer", which is the partition that is 237.36 GB large and NTFS, is the partition that contains Windows. When I try booting from it, I encounter the GNU Grub terminal.
After reading some other posts, I try to find the partition in the hard drive where everything is located, but only get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H28cr.jpg) (I tried ls'ing into the other options, and they all say unsupported file types). How can I remove this remnant of the Ubuntu installation so I can format my hard drive?

Comment: The 100MB is probably the Windows boot partition, created by the Windows installer. There is no Ubuntu installed anywhere, so this is a Windows support question.

Comment: @mikewhatever so does this have anything to do with the failed linux installation?

Comment: The 100MB is shown as the ESP - efi system partition. So you have an UEFI system. You need to be sure to boot Windows installer in UEFI boot mode since drive is gpt partitioned. BIOS & UEFI Windows partitions, note system has totally different format  & meaning between BIOS & UEFI
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx & 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations  & http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi

Comment: Nope, it appears to have nothing at all to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **:-)** As Ubuntu is not having any problems, you'd be better off [asking there](https://superuser.com) instead of here...